# how to append new value to a serialized data before inserting to database using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, serialization

I had a problem inserting new record to database(mysql), because the other data i'm going to insert is in serialized format and the other is date format. I am confused how to append the date time value to the serialized data so that I could insert it at once to the database. The code below shows the insertion of a new data to database, but it always fail to    insert.

```
    function insert_item($data)
        {
            $data[] = array('date_time'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s',now()));
            $this->db->insert('tbl_item',$data);

            return true;

        }
```

the variable $data above holds the serialized data.

Comment: unserialize the serialize data using php function `unserialize()` and you will get an array. add new item in array and serialize again. then insert

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
function insert_item($data)
{
    $data               = unserialize( $data );         #unserialize the data first.
    $data['date_time']  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',now()));   #put the date in the array.
    $data               = serialize( $data );           #serialize again.
    $this->db->insert('tbl_item',$data);
    return true;
}
```